# Rewrite IIS served subdomain with content from other server/port

Tags: iis, iis-6, reverse-proxy, rewrite

Our main web server is using IIS 6 and it obviously catches all port 80 traffic and we have another app served on a non-standard port (8443) that is hosted using Apache.

For example:

- http://www.mydomain.com -> IIS6
- http://subdomain.mydomain.com:8443 -> Apache App
- http://subdomain.mydomain.com -> IIS6

I would like to be able to access the Apache app without using port 8443. That is, IIS should rewrite/proxy content from the Apache app on the different port. Note: I do not want to redirect the user.

- http://subdomain.mydomain.com -> IIS <-> http://subdomain.mydomain.com:8443 -> Apache App

Is this possible? What tools should I use?

Comment: If it would be IIS 7 then it is easy: URL Rewrite module + Application Request Routing (both modules by Microsoft) .. or Helicon Ape (if you prefer Apache style). But you have IIS 6 .. -- I still suggest checking [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/doc/compatibility.htm) -- looks like it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [**Reverse proxy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

And **yes**, this is possible for most web applications.

As to the tools, I think your best bet is to try this with the great [IIRF - Ionic's Isapi Rewrite Filter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) - IIRF works great on IIS6, and it's fast and free.

Though I only had to use Apache's `mod_proxy` to set up a reverse proxy (but IIRF for rewriting urls on other sites), IIRF should be up to the task.

From the FAQ:

> **Can IIRF act as a transparent proxy (like Apache's mod_proxy)?**
>
> Yes. ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse, and ProxyPreserveHost are supported.

The documentation of IIRF contains actually very concise information about setting up (reverse) proxies, as well as some guidance on what to look out for:

- [Http Proxies](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/8f731705-8474-4598-b0f0-e4d67dba9329.htm)
- [ProxyPass instruction and implications](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/d9d3d4d7-7b3a-4418-b290-c297b041ff42.htm)